# select city popup in magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I have a magento store. I want to operate in a city. When one customer visit the store he/she will asked to select his/her area from a dropdown list in a popup. Then the customer is allowed to see the products in the store and shop online.

Example: Suppose My city is Bhubaneswar

```
     Areas: Acharya Vihar, Vani Vihar, Rasulgarh, Barmunda.
```

Comment: specify what do you need? are you looking for city/area database? are you asking how to restrict product list page until the area is selected ???

Comment: @laurent Yes, I have city and area database. how to restrict the store until the customer select the area.

Answer (score 0):

U can create different stores for different places and put this Mage::app()->setCurrentStore($store_id); to make your storeid your current one

Answer (score 0):

For each store you can map several areas, this mapping could be represented in your city area table, by adding a store_id column.
The customer selects the desired store by selecting the city/area, you can then redirect to the desired url with the store scope here you should use

```
Mage::getUrl($path, array(
    '_store'=>'your_store_id'
));
```

To restrict the store as you said, there are different approaches, one is having a default store that is not associated with any area, then you make the categories/products available/enabled only for the stores other than this default one.